# How to send arbitrary numbers and types or arguements

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have a very basic Java question. In order to send an arbitrary number of arguments from one method to another, we can use `varargs`. However, this can only work if the arguments are of the same type. I am wondering is there any way to send an arbitrary number and types of arguments from one method to another. For example, I would like a method to first send 5 arguments of a mixture of `int`  and `String` type. Later, this same method need to be able to send 7 arguements of a mixture of `Boolean` ,`String`,`char` and `double` types. Is there any way to perform such task ? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `Object...` do the job?

Comment: Can you use a varargs of an `Object`?

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you ! I believe both of your solution is similar to TJ's solution below. Thanks for the heads up !

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering is there any way to send an arbitrary number and types of arguments from one method to another.

You can use `Object... args`:

```
void method(Object... args) {
    // ...
}
```

The `int`, `char`, `double` and other primitive-typed arguments will get wrapped in their object wrappers (`Integer`, `Character`, `Double`).

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/etcvSN)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Example {
    void method(Object... args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.method(1, "foo", 2, "bar", 3);
        e.method(true, "foo", 'c', 'd', new Boolean(false), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder , learnt something new today. However, my next task now is to get each of the element assigned to an individual local variable. But thanks for the quick tip.